# Error: <value> expected, got ','

Tags: json

I am trying to save multiple JSON arrays in one document. I have one JSON array formatted like:

```
[{"key":"Math","value":6},{"key":"Biology","value":"8"},{"key":"English","value":"7"},{"key":"Gym","value":"4"}]
```

I would like to save multiples of these in one file, but I get the error:

> json allows only one top level value

I prevented this error by formatting the JSON like:

```
[{"key":"Math","value":6},{"key":"Biology","value":"8"},{"key":"English","value":"7"},{"key":"Gym","value":"4"}], [{"key":"Math","value":6},{"key":"Biology","value":"8"},{"key":"English","value":"7"},{"key":"Gym","value":"4"}]
```

At the ',' between the JSON array's it says: value expected, got ','.

Could someone help me out?

**edit**

Turns out, what I wanted isn't possible. I am trying another JSON format! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can save them into yet another array:

```
[
  [{"key":"Math","value":6}, ...],
  [{"key":"Math","value":6}, ...],
  [{"key":"Math","value":6}, ...],
  [{"key":"Math","value":6}, ...],
  ...
]
```

So, this way the syntax would be correct because you separate the arrays inside of a big array, resulting that you save an array of arrays in the file.

Then, when reading the file, you will get back an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the json sent from the server was missing the square brackets. Dumb server.

Wrong:

```
  {
    "title": "this is title 1" ,
    "text": "this is the text contained 1"
  },
  {
    "title": "this is title 2",
    "text": "this is the text contained 2"
  }
```

Right:

```
[
  {
    "title": "this is title 1",
    "text": "this is the text contained 1"
  },
  {
    "title": "this is title 2",
    "text": "this is the text contained 2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

you should put a top value like "keys"